# RegEx does match in Expresso but doesn't in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, browser

I have written an regex with the help of Expresso. It matches all my samples so I copied it into my JavaScript code. There it doesn't match one of my examples, but why?

RegEx:

```
^(\d{1,2}):?(\d\d)?\s*-\s*(\d{1,2}):?(\d\d)?$
```

Should match:

```
10-12
10:00-12:00
1000-1200
```

In JavaScript 10:00-12:00 doesn't work for me in all browsers like IE9, Chrome, Firefox.
Any ideas?

Update (JavaScript Code):
    input.match(/^(\d{1,2}):?(\d\d)?\s*-\s*(\d{1,2}):?(\d\d)?$/);

Update (solved):
Due some prefiltering the code never got reached. Sorry for that!

Comment: I have the impression that posting your JavaScript code you use to test (and not only the expression) will help diagnose the issue.

Comment: You are right. Added the JS seconds ago.

Comment: Oh no, Iam such an i***t :-) Forgot about some prefiltering, so the code never got reached. Sorry guys *embarrassed*

Comment: @philipooo: You can delete your own question to avoid further embarrassment :)

Answer (score 1):

Testing it in Chrome right now, and it appears to work:

```
var exp = /^(\d{1,2}):?(\d\d)?\s*-\s*(\d{1,2}):?(\d\d)?$/;
exp.test('10-12') // true
exp.test('10:00-12:00') // true
exp.test('1000-1200') // true
exp.test('1000-12005') // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you escape the \'s when placing the expression in your Javascript code?

When embedding it as a string you'll end up writing:

```
  var expression = "^(\\d{1,2}):?(\\d\\d)?\\s* etc
```

Comment: ... or just use the native type syntax: `var expression = /^(\d{1,2}):?(\d\d)?\s*-\s*(\d{1,2}):?(\d\d)?$/;`

Comment: I use the native syntax. Added the js code to the opening post.